# how to grep for "/local" in all perl files in current directory

Tags: shell, unix

I am using the following command to grep for string "/local" in all .pl files,can anyone point what is wrong here?

```
find . *.pl| xargs grep '/local' -sl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `-name` argument, and quote `*.pl`:

```
find . -name "*.pl" | xargs grep '/local' -sl
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is everyone suggesting "find"? The shell can work out your ".pl" files for you:

```
grep  "/local"  *.pl
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just as easily

```
find . -type f -name '*.pl' -exec grep '/local/' {} \;
```

Or a more optimal form if your [find](/questions/tagged/find) supports it, this passes multiple files to grep at a time

```
find . -type f -name '*.pl' -exec grep '/local/' {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

-exec tends to be slow.

I'm partial to:

```
find . -name "*.pl" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -sl '/local'
```

...because it isn't confused by filenames with newlines in them.

Note however that some versions of GNU grep appear to have a memory leak that is triggered by grep commands with a very long list of filenames to search.  Under such circumstances, -exec is more reliable.

Comment: Do you know of any installations where `xargs` is available but not the `{} +` `find` option?